# Show text seconds after page loads (Vanilla JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I have a few div tags that i want to make them appear a few seconds after the page is loaded. You can answer in jQuery but Vanilla JS is preferred. I tried some answers that I've found here on Stack but none worked.

Comment: What have you tried that isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
setTimeout(() => document.querySelector('div').classList.add('show'), 1000);
```

```css
div {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assiming that you are doing it in JS; no Jquery; my suggestion is to wait for DOM to be ready; then add a class to your div;
The following class may have opacity:1 when; by default; your div have opacity:0.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  setTimeout(function(){ 
     console.log("Let's show my div"); 
     document.getElementsById("mydiv").setAttribute("class", "visibleClass");
  }, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("someId").style.display="block";
    }, 2000);
})
```

Your DIV with id "someId" should have style="display:none"